# Crush Linked list nodes

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Given a linked list how do i crush all more than two nodes which are continuous and have same value.
eg
1->3->3->3->5->4->4->4->5->5->2->5
step1 crush 3
1->5->4->4->4->5->5->2->5
step2 crush 4
1->5->5->5->2->5
step3 crush 5
return 1->2->5
I tried below code but its returning 1->5->->5->2->5

```
    public void Crush()
    {
        Node prev = null, current = head;

        if (head == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        prev = current;
        while (current.next != null)
        {



            int k = 0;
            while (current != null && current.next != null && current.data == current.next.data)
            {
                k++;
                current = current.next;
            }

            if (k < 2)
            {

               // prev.next = current;
                current = current.next;


            }
            else
            {
                prev.next = current.next;
                current = current.next;


            }

        }
        head = prev;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1->3->3->3->5->4->4->4->5->5->2->5
               ^

1->5->5->5->2->5
      ^
```

When you remove the run of 4s, it creates a new run of 5s. However, the first 5 has already been skipped over, so only 2 5s are counted.

Anytime a run is removed, you'll need to reprocess the list from the beginning.